# How to store multiple items in database. Confused with database structure

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema

I had a select box where the user will select the list of cities they travelled. After that the admin will search for the users with particular cities.

I am very confused with the structure of the database. There are totally 300 cities. Creating column for each city and store it with boolean on or off, looks a childish technique. Any one help me plz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you've tagged this both `mysql` and `sql-server` - are you using both?

Anyway, this is a standard many-to-many mapping:

**Table: User**

- UserID (int, PK)
- UserName (varchar(50), not null)

**Table: City**

- CityID (int, PK)
- CityName (varchar(50), not null)

**Table: UserCity**

- AssociationID (int, PK)
- UserID (int, FK User, not null)
- CityID (int, FK City, not null)

To retrieve all of the cities for a given user:

```
SELECT c.CityID, c.CityName
FROM User u
INNER JOIN UserCity uc
    ON uc.UserID = u.UserID
INNER JOIN City c
    ON c.CityID = uc.CityID
WHERE u.UserID = @UserID
```

Comment: I've always liked using 'and' clauses instead of joins like so:

select c.CityId, c.CityName from User u, City c, UserCity uc where u.UserId = uc.UserId and c.CityId = uc.CityId and u.UserId = @UserId

I find it easier to read, but do you know if this is maybe slower or has any other drawbacks?

Comment: @Sevas - Both are valid syntax but the explicit join syntax is the ANSI standard and should work on all DBMS.  The implied join is platform-specific (Microsoft and mysql) and harder to write correctly when joining many tables; it's valid, but not commonly used anymore.

Comment: @Aaronaught: Comma-style syntax for *inner* joins is also ANSI standard, supported for the sake of backward compatibility.  It's supported by every popular RDBMS.  But doing *outer* joins with this syntax uses nonstandard syntax in Oracle, Sybase, and Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a column for each city. You simply create a "City" column, where each row is a city. You then have a "Visited" column, where each row is a boolean. In total, there are only two columns.

```
City      |   Visited

London    |     1
Paris     |     0 
New York  |     1
```

etc...

Comment: No. Aaronaught has posted a more detailed answer. You need one column called "UserID" which contains a unique identifier for each user and preferably a column for UserName for a more friendly description of the user.